# How to show Gauge messages in XML report?

Tags: java, getgauge

I'm trying to write messages to the Gauge report using `Gauge.writeMessage`, which works in the HTML report but not in the XML report. Currently using the following:

```
Gauge version: 1.0.4

Plugins
-------
html-report (4.0.6)
java (0.6.9)
screenshot (0.0.1)
xml-report (0.2.1)
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a open issue https://github.com/getgauge/xml-report/issues/8 for the same. Please follow the issue for updates.